# replace all occurence of a TAB by NULL in java 2D array

Tags: java, null, ascii

I'm working on evaluating some data; I have a set of 2D Arrays storing informations. Since I intend to print the data to txt file, that will then be handled by a MySQL DB, I wanted to replace all the separators between the entries (tabs) with null. I tried using .replace, .replaceAll, using a comparaison ( if (array[i][j] == "   ")), but none of it changes the ouput. I wrote the following method, wanting to compare the ascii codes of the array cells to that of TAB, but still no luck:

```
    public static String[][] setTabsToNull(String[][] data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String[][] temp = data.clone();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<data.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<data[0].length;j++){
            if((data[i][j]).getBytes("US-ASCII") == ("  ").getBytes("US-ASCII")){
                temp[i][j] = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

can anyone help me? how can I solve this? 
Simply put, this is what I need to do:
- parse the 2D array (data[][]). and check what the cell contains
  -> if the cell contains a tab, replace the tab by null
  -> else do nothing, and work on the rest of the array

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The clone method on the array only creates a 'shallow' copy. You need to clone each element inside the arrays, as follows:

```
int[][] temp = data.clone();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = data[i].clone();
}


for(int i = 0 ; i<temp.length;i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<temp[0].length;j++){
        if((temp[i][j]).equals("\t"){
            temp[i][j] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, it sill doesn't work....I still get all the tabs between my values when I print out the data...

Comment: Yes... I allready read all the entries from a file, and stored them in my array[][] while using a separator pattern based on the occurence of the tabs... The ouput is consitent with the original data in that sense. Except now every entry including each tab has its own cell, and needs to be altered to NULL for the database...

Comment: I've just tested it on my machine, and it works. Can you provide your printing method?

Comment: I'm simply using a sysout inside two for loops (one for the first, the other for the second "dimension") that prints every row in order...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88001/discussion-between-mcnultyyy-and-spade-johnsson).